# row-wise concatenation of two columns after sorting alphabetically

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hi I would like to create a third column called sorted_gene_pair, which has gene1 and gene2 collapsed, separated by an underscore but ensuring that the genes are in alphabetical order.

This is my data frame:

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(gene1 = c("SEC23A", "SAR1A", "COQ10B", "AP2A2", 
"CUL4A", "PITPNA"), gene2 = c("SEC23B", "SAR1B", "COQ10A", "AP2A1", 
"CUL4B", "PITPNB")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like a tidyverse solution if possible. I am currently trying:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(sorted_gene_pair = paste(sort(c(gene1, gene2)), collapse = '_'))
```

But this is using all of gene 1 and gene 2 columns rather than row wise.

Expected outcome would be:

```
  gene1  gene2 sorted_gene_pair
1 SEC23A SEC23B SEC23A_SEC23B
2  SAR1A  SAR1B SAR1A_SAR1B
3 COQ10B COQ10A COQ10B_COQ10A
4  AP2A2  AP2A1 AP2A1_AP2A2
```

Comment: Your question is hinting a possible answer; use `rowwise()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comment, this now works:

```
d %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sorted_gene_pair = paste(sort(c(gene1, gene2)), collapse = '_'))
```